# How can I clean the text for search using RegEx

Tags: go

I can use the below code to search if the text `str` contains any or both of the `keys`, i.e.if it contains "MS" `or` "dynamics" `or` both of them

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    keys := []string{"MS", "dynamics"}
    keysReg := fmt.Sprintf("(%s %s)|%s|%s", keys[0], keys[1], keys[0], keys[1]) // => "(MS dynamics)|MS|dynamics"
    fmt.Println(keysReg)
    str := "What is MS dynamics, is it a product from MS?"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)` + keysReg)
    matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
    fmt.Println("We found", len(matches), "matches, that are:", matches)
}
```

I want the user to enter his phrase, so I trim unwanted words and characters, then doing the search as per above.
Let's say the user input was: `This,is,a,delimited,string` and I need to build the `keys` variable dynamically to be `(delimited string)|delimited|string` so that I can search for my variable `str` for all the matches, so I wrote the below:

```golang
    s := "This,is,a,delimited,string"
    t := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i),|\.|this|is|a`) // backticks are used here to contain the expression, (?i) for case insensetive
    v := t.Split(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(len(v))
    fmt.Println(v)
```

But I got the output as:

```bash
8
[      delimited string]
```

What is the wrong part in my cleaning of the input text, I'm expecting the output to be:

```bash
2
[delimited string]
```

Here is my [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Zynz02CAcUO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the famous quip from Jamie Zawinski,

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Two things:

- Instead of trying to weed out garbage from the string ("cleaning" it), extract complete words from it instead.
- Unicode is a compilcated matter; so even after you have succeeded with extracting words, you have to make sure your words are properly "escaped" to not contain any characters which might be interpreted as RE syntax before building a regexp of them.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func build(words ...string) (*regexp.Regexp, error) {
    var sb strings.Builder

    switch len(words) {
    case 0:
        return nil, errors.New("empty input")
    case 1:
        return regexp.Compile(regexp.QuoteMeta(words[0]))
    }

    quoted := make([]string, len(words))
    for i, w := range words {
        quoted[i] = regexp.QuoteMeta(w)
    }

    sb.WriteByte('(')
    for i, w := range quoted {
        if i > 0 {
            sb.WriteByte('\x20')
        }
        sb.WriteString(w)
    }
    sb.WriteString(`)|`)
    for i, w := range quoted {
        if i > 0 {
            sb.WriteByte('|')
        }
        sb.WriteString(w)
    }

    return regexp.Compile(sb.String())
}

var words = regexp.MustCompile(`\pL+`)

func main() {
    allWords := words.FindAllString("\tThis\v\x20\x20,\t\tis\t\t,?a!,¿delimited?,string‽", -1)

    re, err := build(allWords...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(re)
}
```

Further reading:

- https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax
- https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#QuoteMeta
- https://pkg.go.dev/unicode#pkg-variables and https://pkg.go.dev/unicode#Categories

Comment: Deeply appreciate your comprehensive answer and comments.

Comment: How can I exclude the words `This, is, a` in the code above from being consider, can I have the output something like: `(This is a delimited string)|delimited|string`

Comment: «How can I exclude the words», take the list of words and delete each of them from the list of words produced by the "extraction" regexp. What is the problem? I mean, it's a matter of running two nested `for` loops.

Comment: I was looking to use the `hat ^ - symbolises not` in the regex to get them excluded, but did not know how to use it.

Comment: Note that I did not touch upon matters I consider dubious. This is one of them: what if the user types "a is this dynamics MS"? Are you okay with removing the first three words? They do not constitute a valid English phrase. The second issue is that the sequence you're building (in addition to alterations) is always "as typed" so if the user types three "meaningful" words, it would look for these three words separated with a single ASCII SPACE character, in that sequence, and not in any other sequence or separated by different whitespace characters.

Comment: «I was looking to use the hat ^ in the regex to get them excluded»—that's what the quote I cited was actually about, honestly. The `^` character only "negates" a so-called "character class" in which is appears; it cannot "negate" words. Some RE engines implement so-called "negative look-arounds", but the Go's engine is not one of them (because having such feature implemented would open a possibility to have an exponential search complexity). I really recommend to not abuse REs for tasks which can be coded by a beginner-grade student of programming (please take no offence—none implied).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, no offence sure, it is not I want to exclude the first 3 words, I just was thinking to exclude some words that are comment and not key words, like the ones mentioned above, and others like `I'm, I've, was, doing, ...` hope you got me.

Comment: last note pls, what is: `\pL+` trying to figure it but could not.

Comment: Ah, I see, looks like parsing a text from CVs ;-) OK. Well, then again, given a list of words, it's not hard to program looking for common sublists which exactly overlap starting at their zeroth elements. Regarding `\pL+`—the syntax `\p{Class}` matches any character of Unicode class `{Class}`; `L` is the class meaning "letters"—that is, any printable characters (hence excluding whitespace and control characters and diacritics etc) excluding punctuation etc. `+` is the regular quantificator meaning "1 or more of the preceding atom". Note that all this is explained in the documents I linked to.